# Expressing functions other than trace in terms of limiting spectral density?

Tags: random-matrices

Suppose $h$ is vector of eigenvalues of a random matrix with unit trace and $e$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$ starting with $e_i=1$ and evolving according the following recurrence:

$$e_i \leftarrow h_i \langle h, e\rangle - 2 h_i e_i $$

Is there a way to express $\|e\|_1$ at time $t$ in terms of limiting spectral density of $h$?

Slides 6-7 of Trogden's RMT [tutorial](https://random-matrix-learning.github.io/pdf/part3.pdf) shows how to express it in terms empirical spectral density by using $u=(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ but I'm curious if this can be applied to the limiting spectral density.

Comment: If limiting spectral density has eigenvalues $h$, then limiting spectral density of this operator eigenvalues of [this differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686487/solving-frac-partial-partial-t-f-hf-int-mathrm-d-i-h-f)