# Solving $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f =hf+ h \int \mathrm {d} i\, h f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

I'm looking for the solution of partial differential equation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(i,t) =\left(a f(i,t) + b\int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} i\, h(i) f(i,t)\right)h(i)$$

Where
$$f(i, 0)=1, \int_0^\infty\mathrm {d} i\, h(i)=1$$

Interesting special case: $h(i)=(i+1)^{-2}$, $a=-2$, $b=1$, want to know $g(t)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}i\ h(i)f(i,t)$.

Background: $g(t)$ gives effect on environment of bird population at time $t$ under continuous version of bird population dynamics model described [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)

Comment: good catch, corrected

Comment: @Gonçalo you are right, this looks like a bug in Mathematica, DSolve gave me incorrect solution. Maybe it's algorithm uses similar assumptions as your (now deleted) answer

Comment: @Gonçalo someone suggested to use Lie Trotter https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445608/solving-frac-partial-partial-tf-h-f-h-int-h-f#comment1150942_445608

Comment: @Gonçalo could you tell me how you solved the $a=0 b\ne 0$ case?

Comment: @Gonçalo btw, if $i$ were discrete, I could apply resolvent [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689034/matrix-resolvent-identity-r-ab-i-r-ab-1r-a), then simplify with Sherman-Morrison to get a closed form expression for Laplace Transform, wondering if there's analogue of Sherman-Morrison for continuous case

Answer (score 5):

The Laplace transform of the function in question can be calculated rather easily. One can Laplace transform in the time coordinate to obtain

$$s\hat F(i,s)=f(i,0)+ah(i)\hat F(i,s)+bh(i)\int_0^\infty h(x)\hat F(x,s)dx$$

Solving for the $\hat F$ yields
$$\hat F(i,s)=\frac{f(i,0)}{s-ah(i)}+\frac{bh(i)}{s-ah(i)}\int_0^\infty h(x)\hat F(x,s)dx$$
Integrate the equation against $h(i)$ and solve the now self-consistent equation to obtain the value of the inner product $\langle h,\hat F\rangle:=\int_0^\infty dx h(x)\hat F(x,s)$

$$\langle h,\hat F\rangle(s)=\frac{\int_0^\infty dx\frac{f(x,0)h(x)}{s-ah(x)}}{1-b\int_0^\infty dx\frac{h^2(x)}{s-ah(x)}}$$

For the specific values provided in the question, the integrals can be computed analytically:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{h(x)}{s+2h(x)}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2s}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}}$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{h^2(x)}{s+2h(x)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-
\sqrt{\frac{s}{2}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}}\right)$$

which finally yields for the two functions in question

$$\langle{h,\hat F}\rangle=\frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}}}{\sqrt{\frac{s}{2}}\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{s}{2}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}}\right)}$$

$$\hat F(i,s)=\frac{(i+1)^2}{2+s(i+1)^2}+\frac{1}{s(i+1)^2+2}\frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}}}{\sqrt{\frac{s}{2}}\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{s}{2}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}}\right)}$$

Inverting these LT's seems to be at least upon a first glance, nontrivial, however a numerical inversion is always possible.

Comment: What do you do after "integrate the equation against $h(i)$? I get terms like $\langle h^2, \hat{F}\rangle$, how do you group these with $\langle h, \hat{F}\rangle$

Comment: You need to solve for $\hat F$ first in the first equation. Then if you integrate against $h(i)$ you obtain a linear equation in $\langle h,\hat F\rangle$, which you can solve for the result in equation 2. Edited with some details.