# Tricky Laplace Transform problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

Can someone see a way to find an expression for $g(t)$ defined as inverse Laplace Transform below? Perhaps in the limit of large $t$

$$g(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{I(s)}{\frac{1}{J(s)}-1}\right](t)\\
I(s)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}i\ \frac{h(i)}{s+2h(i)}\\
J(s)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}i\ \frac{h(i)^2}{s+2h(i)}\\
h(i) = \frac{(1+i)^{-p}}{\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}j\  (1+j)^{-p}}\ \\
p>1$$

Motivation: this gives a way to approximate $g(t)$ in the in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686487/solving-frac-partial-partial-t-f-hf-int-mathrm-d-i-h-f) for $a=-2,b=1,h(i)=\ldots$

I can [solve it numerically](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-inverse-laplace-transform.nb) for $p=1.1$, but interested in symbolic form

[image]

Comment: $h_i$ referred to $h$ being a function of $i$, replaced with $h(i)$ to avoid confusion

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the reason for using $i$ is because original problem is discrete, with $i$ referring to $i$'th dimension, $h(i)$ referring to Hessian curvature in that dimension. This is a continuous approximation. [background](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)