# Simplifying arctan expression using Puiseux series

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Mathematica gives me the following expression which works well for $s$ near $0$, any idea how to derive this manually?

$$\left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}{\pi -2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right)^{-1} \approx \frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}$$

```
expr = 1/(s/2 + (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s])/(\[Pi] - 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[s]/Sqrt[2]]));
asymp = Asymptotic[expr, s -> 0]
```

This appears to be the first term in Series expansion below. Using $x=2s^2$ replacement, the series looks like below

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  & \text{order} & \text{expr} \\
  & 0 & \frac{\pi }{2 x}-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-1 \\
  & 1 & \frac{1}{8} \left(8 \pi +\pi ^3\right) x+\frac{\pi }{2 x}-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-1 \\
  & 2 & \frac{1}{48} \left(-32-36 \pi ^2-3 \pi ^4\right) x^2+\frac{1}{8} \left(8 \pi +\pi ^3\right) x+\frac{\pi }{2 x}-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-1 \\
\end{array}$$

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mathematica-asymptotic.nb)

Comment: What is Puisseux about this? Replace $s=2x^2$ and everything has integer powers.

Comment: Would not a loglog plot be a better plot to see the local expansion around $s=0$?

Comment: This belongs on [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @LutzLehmann if I ask for more terms I get result below, isn't that Puissex series? Trying to figure out how I would derive this manually $$O\left(s^{3/2}\right)+\frac{1}{96} \left(-32-36 \pi ^2-3 \pi ^4\right) s+\frac{\pi  \left(8+\pi ^2\right) \sqrt{s}}{8 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}+\frac{1}{4} \left(-4-\pi ^2\right)$$

Comment: Yes, it is. The concern was why introduce $\sqrt{s}$ at all, it looks somewhat artificial without context. The expansion can also done in the above-mentioned $x$, using only power or Laurent series.

Comment: @LutzLehmann for context, this is the solution to differential equation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694070/998). Edited post with expansion in $x$, the leading term is $O(x^{-1})$, this is not the usual Taylor series, hence trying to figure out how coefficients are obtained

Comment: This is just a limit problem not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote your expression by $f(s)$. Introducing the new variable $z>0$ via $s=2z^2$ yields
$$
zf(2z^2 ) = \cfrac{1}{{z + \cfrac{1}{{\pi/2  - \arctan (z)}}}}.
$$
By analytic continuation, the right-hand side is a holomorphic function of $z$ in the disc $|z|<0.492912456\ldots$, where $-0.492912456\ldots$ is the unique real root of the equation $z\operatorname{arccot}(z)=-1$. Its Maclaurin series is
$$
zf(2z^2 ) = \frac{\pi }{2} - \frac{{\pi ^2  + 4}}{4}z + \frac{{\pi (\pi ^2  + 8)}}{8}z^2  -  \ldots \,.
$$
Thus, on the Riemann surface associated with the square-root,
$$
f(s) = \frac{\pi }{{2^{1/2} }}s^{ - 1/2}  - \frac{{\pi ^2  + 4}}{4} + \frac{{\pi (\pi ^2  + 8)}}{8}s^{3/2}  -  \ldots 
$$
provided $|s|<0.485925370\ldots\,$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $\tan^{-1}(x)\approx x$ if $x\ll 1$, so
\begin{align}
\frac{s}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}{\pi -2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}&\approx
\frac{s}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}{\pi -\sqrt{2s}} \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2s}}{\pi}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\frac{s}{2}}+\frac{1}{1-\frac{\sqrt{2s}}{\pi}}\right) \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2s}}{\pi}\left(1+O(\sqrt{s})\right),
\end{align}
hence
$$
\left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s}}{\pi -2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right)^{-1}\approx\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2s}}\quad\text{if $s\ll 1$.}
$$